# Is it possible to format Tooltip-Text (bold, underline... etc)?

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, coding-style, tooltip

I want to make some passages of a standard tooltip bold in a WinForms application. Is this possible?

If not, is there a (free) tooltip component that allows me to style them (preferably also border and background)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in ASP.Net or WinForms?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this type : [Balloon tool tip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ballontooltip.aspx). This let you have some bold title and some color option. You might be able to modify the source to get underline, italic and bold inside the message.

[image]

### Update:

You can modify the drawing of the ToolTip (and the FONT object of the text). [This is how to do it](http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/10/implementing-custom-tooltip-in-c.html). The code in this link is for the normal ToolTip, not the Balloon I posted above.

Answer (score -2):

If you know a little about html, you can just write the tooltip like this:

```
_toolTip.SetToolTip(button, String.Format("<font face=\"Microsoft Yahei\" color=\"blue\">{0}</font>", Tooltip Text));
```