# How to make a tooltip show formatted text?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to format Tooltip-Text (bold, underline… etc) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250774/is-it-possible-to-format-tooltip-text-bold-underline-etc)

I am creating a program has some element and when user moves the mouse on it, the program will show some information in a tooltip. But the properties "Tooltip" of control only accepts a simple `string`. I need some way to show formatted text in the tooltip (specifying bold, font size, etc).

Please help me, thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible with the default tooltip provider (unless you handle the drawing manually) but you can use a free 3rd party component as suggested here: [Is it possible to format Tooltip-Text (bold, underline... etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250774/is-it-possible-to-format-tooltip-text-bold-underline-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Standard tool tips do not support formatting.

You need to either implement your own tool tip or find a custom one that someone else has written.